# How to make a singleton class threadsafe?

Tags: java, class, singleton, class-design

I am implementing a singleton class in Java to make sure no more than one instance of the class is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is to use an enum with a single instance. This has the added benefit of being serializable and guaranteeing singleton-ness against serialization and reflection, which no "straightforward" Singleton implementation does (private? I have reflection, I scoff derisively at your access modifiers!). It's also very simple to implement:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    // fields and methods go here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The best way to make a singleton? Use an enum.

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public void foo(){ ... }
}

// Usage:
Singleton.INSTANCE.foo();
```

You get lots of help from the VM not only to avoid double instantiation, but it also helps you avoid deserialization corruption.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Singleton {
  public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
  private Singleton() { ... }
}
```

Using a static instance variable is preferred to the internal "Holder" class. If you like, you can also make the static member private and provide a method for accessing it, but all that does is add another method call to the stack.

Comment: It rather depends what you're trying to achieve as to what is preferred - the holder gives you a lazy singleton, the simpler version doesn't give you lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, it does. Java doesn't load classes until they're first used.

Comment: Not entirely true. It loads them when they're first referenced, e.g. in the method signature of another class.

Comment: Accessor methods are normally inlined by the VM. Do not choose public field over accessor to get rid of a "method call on the stack" - in your code, it will look like a method call, but in reality, it'll be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

What about lazy instanciation: getInstance() returns the singleton or create it if it is the first call.

```
 public class MySingleton
 {
     private static MySingleton instance;

     private MySingleton()
     {
         // construct object . . .
     }

     // For lazy initialization
     public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance()
     {
         if (instance==null)
         {
             instance = new MySingleton();
         }
         return instance;
     }

     // Remainder of class definition . . .
 }
```

Comment: Lazy instantiation is almost never necessary, and if it is, Java loads classes lazily, so creating the instance in the declaration actually *is* lazy instantiation - without synchronization overhead (in very rare cases that's not lazy enough and skaffman's answer is better).

Comment: Also note this implementation synchronizes every attempt to obtain a reference to the instance. Since most code will do something like:
Singleton.getInstance.doSomething();
Singleton.getInstance.doSomethingElse();
The overall effect would be additional synchronization severely limiting concurrency with no thread safety guarantees in terms of member access/mutation.

Comment: Double-checked locking in java is broken http://www.javaworld.com/jw-02-2001/jw-0209-double.html
In short, this way of guaranteeing that this class is instantiated only once may result in hard-to-find concurrency issues. Never use this.

Comment: DCL is non-broken as of Java 5. Check out http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html, scroll down to "Under the new Java Memory Model".

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are not threadsafe per default. The common way to create a singleton is to have a factory method that handles creation of the one instance. That way you can control instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about concurrency, you won't be using shared global state.

Comment: If the singleton holds the accumulation of results from a singular parallelized problem why not? A singleton epitomizes global state, and as such it would be a fair usage scenario.

Comment: There are several use cases for classes represented with only one instance that is shared between processes. A typical well designed webapp using spring will probably have a bunch of classes instantiated in singleton scope, shared between worker threads.